Best way to have users validate accuracy of AI authored text without it feeling too heavy handed?

Our MVP product will use OCR to scan patient records (e.g., handwritten, faxed, digital, etc.) and uses AI to write a patient summary for healthcare providers
There are key patient data points that we would like the user to validate against the original source document to insure it is accurate (imagine a blurry 8 being interpreted as a 0).
We will show the user the interpreted data on one side, and the original patient document on the other so they can match them and verify that it is correct
If it is incorrect, the user can type in the correct information that they are reading off the document themselves
My team is concerned about both patient safety and company liability if the user misses a mismatch

What are some ways we can have the user carefully validate the AI information without it feeling too heavy handed?


It is not clear how it is 'heavy-handed'? Please provide sample AI response. Is the question about the reliability of the response as mentioned '8' should read as 8? Or is it about the presentation of the response?

I would assume that being heavy-handed is a good thing in this context. With something as important as human healthcare I would intentionally add in extra 'heavy-handedness' - have multiple humans be required to sign-off on the transcript, not just one person.

Apologies for not being clearer- yes, we need the user to validate that what AI interprets as an '8' from say, a scan of a faxed sheet of paper on the right, populates correctly as '8.'
Having a user validate each data point feels a little tedious. We could have just 1 CTA button to confirm that the user has validated all data points, but I have concerns that they may not examine each detail, first
